# Upgrade to 4.4 lost WYSIWIG

Tags: drupal, upgrade, wysiwyg, lts

Just wanted to share here in case anyone else can benefit from my experience.  I upgraded my civi drupal installation recently from Civi 4.2.6 to Civi LTS 4.4.19.   Somehow the setting for sharing drupal's wysiwyg editor got lost. I don't know if that's a problem with the installation, or if there was some unique problem on my system.  In any case, once I figured out what was going on, I just had to reset as per http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Configuring+CiviCRM+to+Use+the+Default+Drupal+Editor.

Also, FYI I see here that this setting is going away unless someone builds an extension.  https://civicrm.org/blogs/colemanw/big-changes-wysiwyg-editing-47

Comment: Just adding that it turns out this didn't work properly in 4.4. When I set this to share drupal editor there were several bad consequences having to do with civimail (see q 7453) and also that the wysiwig editor no longer showed to edit an event description on on the info page when I also had a RichTextEditor type custom event field.   I ended up falling back to ckeditor and manually configuring it to be as similar as possible to my drupal one.  That resolved both problems.